# AttributeError: 'CallbackQuery' object has no attribute 'text'- на 27 строке, а так же он жалуется на bot.polling()- SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, telebot

```
import telebot
from telebot import types 

bot = telebot.TeleBot('5846233100:AAEJJpDJG6XTrlDxUBfh-cBHqf7S6hhAPvU')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def get_user_info(message):
    markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Начинаем!', callback_data = 'yes')
    markup_inline.add(item_yes)
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, я рад приветствовать тебя в этом боте, здесь ты можешь потренироваться в сдаче диф зачета. Желаешь начать?', reply_markup = markup_inline)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, answer)

def answer(call):
    if call.data == 'yes':
        markup_reply = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
        item_otvet = types.KeyboardButton('V=ST ; V=V0t-at^2/2')
        item_otvet0 = types.KeyboardButton('V=S/T ; V=V0t+at')
        markup_reply.add(item_otvet, item_otvet0)
        msg = bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Формула скорости при равномерном и равноускоренном движении', reply_markup = markup_reply)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, one_question)
@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True)
        

def one_question(message):
    if message.text == 'V=ST ; V=V0t-at^2/2':
        msg = bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Формула скорости при равномерном и равноускоренном движении')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, two_question)
    elif message.text == 'V=S/T ; V=V0t+at':
        question = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
        item_go = types.KeyboardButton('S=VT ; S=V0t-at^2/2 ; S=V^2-V0^2/2a')
        item_q = types.KeyboardButton('S=VT ; S=V0t+at^2/2 ; S=V^2-V0^2/2a')
        question.add(item_go, item_q)
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Это правильный вариант ответа! Продолжаем! Формула перемещения при равномерном и равноускоренном движении', reply_markup = question)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, three_question)
@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True)

def two_question(message):
    if message.text == 'S=VT ; S=V0t+at^2/2 ; S=V^2-V0^2/2a':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Это правильный вариант ответа! Продолжаем!')
    elif message.text == 'S=VT ; S=V0t+at^2/2 ; S=V^2-V0^2/2a':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Не правильно. Правильный вариант ответа: V=S/T ; V=V0t+at ,  пропиши /start ,чтобы повторить попытку.')
@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True)



bot.polling()
```

писал бота теста по физике

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: можете посмотреть, я обновил информация об ошибке